# jquery how to Completely delete the progress bar or dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I added a progressbar when my app raise ajax application, this progress bar was prompted by a dialog, I write below code in ajaxStop function:

```
progressbarDialog.dialog("close");
progressbar.progressbar("close");
this.appendDOM.empty(); `
```

It works well when the first ajax happens, but from the second time, a dialog and progresss bar display un-normal, a blank part will show under the normal part, I think  the dialog may be not deleted but hided, can anyone explain this issue? how can the dialog/progress bar total be deleted?

version 2:

```
progressbarDialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
```

do works, but my dialog is a modal dialog, when I raise application more and more time, the back-ground color will become more and more dark~~~~
below is my function, can anyone help me~

GSMProgressBar.prototype.showProgressBar = function(){
    this.appendDOM.empty();
    this.appendDOM.prepend("");
    var progressbar = $( "#progressBarDialog #progressbar" );
    var progressbarDialog = $("#progressBarDialog");
    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    var timeoutOption;
    if(this.config='fast'){
        timeoutOption = 300;
    }else if(this.config='slow'){
        timeoutOption = 800;
    }else{
        //default 250
        timeoutOption = 500;
    }
    progressbar.progressbar({value:false}); 
       function progress() {
            var val = progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) || 0;
            if ( val < 75 ) { 
                progressbar.progressbar( "value", val + Math.random() * 25  ); 
                 }
            if(val<99){
                setTimeout( progress, timeoutOption );
                }
         }
    setTimeout( progress, 10 );
    progressbarDialog.dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 110,
        width: 400
    });
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
    }); 
    $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
        progressbarDialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
    });
    };

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
progressbarDialog.dialog("close");
```

to

```
progressbarDialog.dialog('destroy').remove();
```

this destroys the dialog and removes the element that holds the dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#YOUR_PROGRESS_BAR_ID").remove();
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that you are initializing progressbar after deleting from DOM.